# Is there any alternative for hibernatetemplates getHibernateTemplate().find(String queryString,@Nullable Object... value) method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are moving from `Spring` **3.2.10.RELEASE** to **5.2.8.RELEASE** and **Hibernate 3.3.1.GA** to **5.4.27.Final** as well. I am trying to find an alternative to this line of code:

```
getHibernateTemplate().find(String query, Object values);
```

This returns a List containing the results of the query execution

`find()` method of hibernateTemplate `class` has `deprecated`. I need your help to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The common Spring method to retrieve data is to use a Data Access Object or a DAO. Spring JPA allows you to create interfaces that extend `CrudRepository` that can pull your data from the database and figure out what to do based on the method name and annotations. Something like this

```
public interface MyEntityDao extends CrudRepository<MyEntity,Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT m FROM MyEntity ...")
    List<MyEntity> findAllMyEntity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply but this is the option I ended up going with:

```java
List<yourObject> variable = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(HQL).setParameter(int id, otherObject.getId()).list();
```